# jquery onclick change value22

Tags: jquery

I have code that should change the anochor and the id value when clicking on it.
The value and the anchor are changing, but only 1 time.
can you tell me why it's not working?

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="enable-edit-button">EDit</a>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#enable-edit-button").click(function()
    {
        $(this).attr("id","save-edit-button");
        $(this).html("SAVE");

    });

    $("#save-edit-button").click(function()
    {
        $(this).attr("id","enable-edit-button");
        $(this).html("EDIT");   
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate of a question about changing class dynamically, but the issue and solution are the same when changing ID dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is defined here..
[Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

```
$('body').on('click', '#save-edit-button', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(document).on('click', "#enable-edit-button", function ()
    {
        $(this).attr("id", "save-edit-button");
        $(this).html("SAVE");

    });
    $(document).on('click', "#save-edit-button", function ()
    {
        $(this).attr("id", "enable-edit-button");
        $(this).html("EDIT");
    });

});
```

Comment: Don't just dump code, explain the problem and how your answer solves it.